Image offset in swiftui
I keep learning swiftui in my free time and now I am making an app with API calls and a List, everything is fine until I need to make an offset of an image, I can do it but the image gets cut, here you have an image to see it.
This is what I have

This is what I want:

Why is the image cut off?
Here is my code:
PokemonItem
struct PokemonItem:View {
let pokemon: ApiNetwork.Pokemon
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        PokemonItemLeft(pokemon: pokemon)
        Spacer()
        PokemonItemRight(pokemon: pokemon)
    }.frame(height: 115)
     .background(colorForPokemonType(type: pokemon.details?.types.first?.type.name ?? ""))
     .cornerRadius(16)
     .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
     .padding(.bottom, 16)
    
     }
}

PokemonItemLeft
struct PokemonItemLeft: View {
let pokemon: ApiNetwork.Pokemon
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Image("DotsImage")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 100)
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .padding(.leading, 64)
        if let id = pokemon.details?.id {
            Text(formatPokemonID(id))
                .font(.caption)
                .foregroundColor(Color.pokemonId)
                .bold()
        } else {
            Text("ID: Unknown")
        }
        Text(pokemon.name.capitalized).font(.title2).foregroundColor(Color.white).bold()
    }.padding(.leading, 20)
}
}

PokemonItemRight
struct PokemonItemRight: View {
let pokemon: ApiNetwork.Pokemon

var body: some View {
        VStack {
            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/official-artwork/\(pokemon.details?.id ?? 0).png")) { image in
                image
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 130, height: 130)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                    .padding(.trailing, 18)
                    .offset(y: -20)
                    .zIndex(1)
            } placeholder: {
                ProgressView()
            }
        }
        .padding(.leading, 20)
    }
}

This is why I am using ItemLeft and ItemRight

This is the function to change the background color
func colorForPokemonType(type: String) -> Color {
let cardColors: [String: Color] = [
    "grass": Color(red: 139/255, green: 190/255, blue: 138/255),
    "fire": Color(red: 255/255, green: 167/255, blue: 86/255),
    "water": Color(red: 88/255, green: 171/255, blue: 246/255),
    "poison": Color(red: 159/255, green: 110/255, blue: 151/255),
    "normal": Color(red: 181/255, green: 185/255, blue: 196/255),
    "bug": Color(red: 139/255, green: 214/255, blue: 116/255),
    "flying": Color(red: 116/255, green: 143/255, blue: 201/255),
    "electric": Color(red: 242/255, green: 203/255, blue: 85/255),
    "ground": Color(red: 247/255, green: 133/255, blue: 81/255),
    "fairy": Color(red: 235/255, green: 168/255, blue: 195/255),
    "fighting": Color(red: 208/255, green: 65/255, blue: 100/255),
    "psychic": Color(red: 234/255, green: 93/255, blue: 96/255),
    "rock": Color(red: 186/255, green: 171/255, blue: 130/255),
    "ghost": Color(red: 85/255, green: 106/255, blue: 174/255),
    "ice": Color(red: 97/255, green: 206/255, blue: 192/255),
    "dragon": Color(red: 15/255, green: 106/255, blue: 192/255)
]

return cardColors[type] ?? Color.gray

}
Here is the small problem with the first item of the list

Thanks a lot!

Image is a View, not an image. It is the thing-that-displays-the-spiderman-image, not the spiderman image itself. Well, the Image as a view does not move or get resized because of .offset; its drawn content is shifted up. So the top of the content is cut off.

And how can I solve it?

Can you explain what your desired output looks like?

I just want to see the whole image out of the green box. I have edited main answer

There is no "green box" in your code.

Sorry, I have edited my main question because I was using another code  just to make the question and to understand the answer, now in the main answer I have wrote my main code, hope it helps to understand my problem better. Sorry for bother you.

The reason your Pokemon is getting cropped because it's inside a HStack.
HStack and VStack arranges its subviews horizontally and vertically respectively.
To fix this, think your card as layers, base layer being the background, first layer being the pokemon image. Using ZStack you can achieve required results. The reason that ZStack works is that it "overlays" its subviews.
Have written sample code below with some hardcoded values for the same.
ContentView
for testing purposes
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        PokemonItem()
    }
}

PokemonItem
It has 2 layers: one base layer and one content layer
struct PokemonItem: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            //base card
            colorForPokemonType(type: "grass")
                .cornerRadius(16)
            
            //content
            PokemonItemDetails()
        }
        .frame(height: 115)
        .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
        .padding(.bottom, 16)
    }
}

PokemonItemDetails
A wrapper for content that needs to be displayed on the Card.
struct PokemonItemDetails: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            PokemonItemLeft()
            Spacer()
            PokemonItemRight(id: 1)
        }
    }
}

PokemonItemLeft
struct PokemonItemLeft: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Spacer()
            Image("DotsImage")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 100)
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .padding(.leading, 64)
            Text("#001")
                .font(.caption)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .bold()
            Text("bulbasaur".capitalized)
                .font(.title2)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .bold()
                .padding(.bottom, 10)
        }.padding(.leading, 20)
    }
}

PokemonItemRight
struct PokemonItemRight: View {
    let id: Int
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/official-artwork/\(id).png")) { image in
                image
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 130, height: 130)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                    .padding(.trailing, 18)
                    .offset(y: -20)
                    .zIndex(1)
            } placeholder: {
                ProgressView()
            }
        }
        .padding(.leading, 20)
    }
}

result:

PS: to get extact positioning of dots, you'll just need to tweak some paddings and it should work fine.
Hope this solves your query.

Oh wow, I didn't know that difference between zStack and V/HStack, thank you very much for the explanation, the problem is that I need to have two items, left and right, to be able to show the card correctly, I have updated the main question showing the entire card.
I don't know if there is another option to do it, I am learning and I thought this will be the best to start, dividing the card in left and right structs.

@Tomas please send PokemonItemLeft. will update the answer according to your requirements.

Done, I have updated the main question.

@Tomas have edited the answer with your requirements. Hope this helps.

That's it! It works fine now, to understand what I'm doing, when using ZStack I can give it a height of, for example, 100, then the content inside can be more than 100 and it will come out of the edges like what I wanted but, if I use HStack or VStack with a height of 100, everything that exceeds those 100 will be cut off? Am I understanding this correctly?

Yes, definitely that's what is happening. Happy Coding!

Perfect, thanks a lot, if I can ask another small thing... I have updated the main question with a new small problem, the problem is that the image of the first list item, appears a bit cut because off... I don't know

You'd need to tweak the top padding of PokemonItem. It's getting cropped because of the frame of List. adding padding will give room to the image.

Oh wow, I have tried all but I have never thought that point, thanks a lot.
Is there any option to keep in touch with you?
